# debian12 installed wazuh-manager , it can‘t scan itself vulnerability

Tags: wazuh

wazuh-modulesd:vulnerability-detector   Manager 4.3.11  Packages    debian12

2023/10/16 17:29:26 wazuh-modulesd:vulnerability-detector: INFO: (5431): Starting vulnerability scan.
2023/10/16 17:29:26 wazuh-modulesd:vulnerability-detector: INFO: (5435): The analysis can not be launched because there are no target agents.
2023/10/16 17:29:26 wazuh-modulesd:vulnerability-detector: INFO: (5472): Vulnerability scan finished.

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved， the wazuh 4.3.11 is too old to debian 12,  The support for Debian 12 is intended to be released in 4.6.0.